# Life cycle inventory data or information concerning Ferrocyanide production

Tags: environmental-impact, life-cycle-analysis, industrial-production

I am working in the modelling and environmental evaluation of redox flow batteries based on Anthraquinone and Ferrocyanide. Currently I am having difficulties in finding information on how Ferrocyanide is produced, for example as Potassium Ferrocyanide.

Does anyone know where I can find information or data concerning its production? At an industrial scale if possible. I searched but could not find any inventory data concerning Ferrocyanide.

Thanks in advance for any information you can give me.

Comment: Welcome to Sustainable Living! [This website](https://www.lcacommons.gov/lca-collaboration/search/query=Ferrocyanide) at least has information on Ferrocyanide, but I'm not sure if those files you can download are useful.

Comment: Thanks for sending the information. I will check it. Regards,